# how to list all the webservices listed under a server?

Tags: c#, web-services, server

I am trying to list all the webservices and their status by just giving the name of the server,i am able to access the server and list the window services and their corresponding status but how do i proceed doing the same with webservices using c#?

thanks in advance

Comment: what kind of webservice? WCF?

Comment: You could do a ping on the server with a specific port range--> if you get an answer the service is active

Comment: @DennisLarisch All that is going to do is tell you something responds to port 80 which for all we know is being used by _Miss Piggy's Perfume Perculator_ software and not say IIS

Comment: Thats true, was just an idea